# Flask app won't load in browser

Tags: python, redis, flask, redis-py

I'm just getting started with flask and I'm trying to build the tutorial micro-blog using redis. Here is my app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
import redis
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

app.config.update(dict(
    DEBUG = True,
    ))

POOL = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    r = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool = POOL)
    print r
    pipe = r.pipeline()
    print pipe
    last_ten = pipe.zrange('post:created_on', 0, 9)
    print last_ten
    posts = []
    for post in last_ten:
        posts.append(pipe.hgetall('{}{}'.format('post:', post)))


    print posts
    pipe.execute()

    return render_template('index.html', posts)



@app.route('/new', methods = ['POST'])
def addPost():
    r = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool = POOL)

    title = request.form['title']
    author = request.form['author']
    now = datetime.now()

    pipe = r.pipeline()
    post_format = 'post:'
    pid = pipe.incr('post')
    pipe.hmset('{}{}'.format(post_format,pid), {'title':title, 'author':author})
    pipe.zadd('post:created_on', pid = now)
    pipe.execute()

    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When I run `python testapp.py` I get

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
* Restarting with reloader
```

However the page never loads at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` nor does it return an error. It just hangs, trying to load forever. I've left it for a while and it just keeps on going. I'm not sure what would be causing this but thank you for your help.

**UPDATE:** I have added several `print` statements in my `index` view to see what is happening while that code runs and this is what was printed to the terminal.

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
* Restarting with reloader
StrictRedis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
StrictPipeline<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
StrictPipeline<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
```

Comment: Are you sure Redis is running and listening on it's default port (6379) ? You can check by using a Terminal/CMD, launching redis-cli and typing "PING" + enter. It should answer "PONG".

Comment: Use `PRINT` too see where it gets too

Comment: Pascal, yes I am positive the redis server was running as expected, I was interacting it through the python shell.
Joe, I've added several `print` statements as per your suggestions and included the results in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved the issue. The problem was that I opened a `pipeline` and tried acting on the data retrieved from the db before I had called `pipe.execute`. I'm still working on getting the overall function to work but this is how I solved this particular issue.

Comment: That is correct. Before you call execute, the StrictRedis pipeline's data is still local.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I am also facing the same issue.